# Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

After an update I can't access my encrypted disk.

When trying to do so :

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda8 Documents


Failed to setup dm-crypt key mapping
Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher (check syslog for more info)
```

I did:

```
lsmod | grep -i aes
aesni_intel           167997  3
aes_x86_64             16719  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    12757  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            12649  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            12572  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 18553  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
```

Also:

```
lsmod | grep -i dm-mod
lsmod | grep -i dm-crypt
lsmod | grep -i sha256
lsmod | grep -i xts
```

and they didn't return anything,so,I modprobe all of these but I have still the same issue.

Comment: What does `zgrep CONFIG_CRYPTO_XTS /proc/config.gz` return?

Comment: @Tom Yan:CONFIG_CRYPTO_XTS=m

Comment: so is the `xts` module loaded (or can it be loaded)?

Comment: @Tom Yan:Yes, I am using `modprobe xts` also.But still the same

Comment: So have you checked you syslog as told? (`dmesg`?)

Comment: @Tom Yan:Yes,but I can't find something..I am using `dmesg |grep crypt` and `journalctl |grep crypt` or `grep aes` or similar..

Comment: You don't really need grep for that. You just need to see if any new messages pop up after you failed to run what you wanted (btw, what's the exact command you ran that gives you those error? i think you should add it to your post)

Comment: @Tom Yan:I updated .In dmesg ,after running the command I can't see any new message.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but, have you run lukFormat on `/dev/sda8` before luksOpen?

Comment: @Tom Yan:Yes,of course.I am using this partiotion for a long time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35695/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-george).

Answer (score 2):

According to [`man cryptsetup`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup) :

> The available combinations of ciphers, modes, hashes and key sizes depend on kernel support. ***See `/proc/crypto`*** for a list of available options. You might need to load additional kernel crypto modules
>   in order to get more options.

Also try `cryptsetup --help` to show defaults.

---

FYI: My (Linux Mint) cryptsetup works fine with default LUKS. My `cryptsetup --help` has this at the end:

```
Default compiled-in device cipher parameters:
    loop-AES: aes, Key 256 bits
    plain: aes-cbc-essiv:sha256, Key: 256 bits, Password hashing: ripemd160
    LUKS1: aes-xts-plain64, Key: 256 bits, LUKS header hashing: sha1, RNG: /dev/urandom
```

And my `lsmod` contains no mention of sha, aes, or xts, but does have:

`dm_crypt               22653  0` (note the underscore, not a dash like in your Q)

And my `/proc/crypto` has:

```
$ grep name.*aes /proc/crypto|cut -d : -f 2
 cbc(aes)
 aes
```

Comment: :Thanks for the info.I downgraded to previous kernel and it works fine now.